# Loop R error: replacement has length zero

Tags: r, runtime-error

This is my code where I explain some parts where I think there is a problem.

```
set.seed(5623)
t_llegada <- (1:30)
t_viaje <- (1:30)
t_intervalo<- (1:30)
#Prob. morning
pllegadaM <- rexp(30,rate=0.81)  #Prob
pviajeM <- rexp(30,rate=30.47) #Prob
pinterM<- rexp(30,rate=0.12) #Prob
#Prob afternoon
pllegadaT <- rexp(30,rate=0.096)  #Prob
pviajeT <- rexp(30,rate=31.80) #Prob
pinterT<- rexp(30,rate=0.97) #Prob
#Prob night
pllegadaN <- rexp(30,rate=0.12) #Prob
pviajeN <- rexp(30,rate=32.12) #Prob
pinterN<- rexp(30,rate=0.9) #Prob
sim <-NULL

##Dimension variables:
minutos.dia<-numeric(600)
min.llegada <- minutos.dia
min.salida <- minutos.dia
tinterval <- minutos.dia
tservicio.llegada<-minutos.dia

##Sample time with probs
tintervalM <- sample(t_intervalo,size=1, replace=TRUE, prob= pinterM)
tllegadasM <- sample(t_llegada,size=1,replace = TRUE,prob=pllegadaM) 
tviajeM <- sample(t_viaje,size=1,replace = TRUE,prob=pviajeM)
tintervalT <- sample(t_intervalo,size=1, replace=T, prob= pinterT)
tllegadasT <- sample(t_llegada,size=1,replace = TRUE,prob=pllegadaT) 
tviajeT <- sample(t_viaje,size=1,replace = TRUE,prob=pviajeT)
tintervalN <- sample(t_intervalo,size=1, replace=T, prob= pinterN)
tllegadasN <- sample(t_llegada,size=1,replace = TRUE,prob=pllegadaN) 
tviajeN <- sample(t_viaje,size=1,replace = TRUE,prob=pviajeN)

##Count first person
min.llegada[1]<- 1
tinterval[1]<- 1
min.salida[1]<-tinterval[1]+tviajeM[1] 

###Save in data frame "Sim"
uno <- data.frame (caso = 1,
               minuto_llegada = min.llegada[1],
               minuto_inicio_del_viaje = tinterval[1],
               Tiempo_viaje = tviajeM [1], 
               minuto_salida_del_cliente = min.salida[1]) 
sim <- rbind(sim, uno)

##Loop to asigne probs acording to number cases 
for (c in 2:600){
  tllegadasM[c] <- if(c <300){sample(t_llegada,size=1,replace =TRUE,prob=pllegadaM)#VAL 2
  }                     else{
sample(t_llegada,size=1,replace = TRUE,prob=pllegadaT)}

  tviajeM[c] <- if(c<300){sample(t_viaje,size=1,replace = TRUE,prob=pviajeM)#VAL 3
  }                     
  else{
sample(t_viaje,size=1,replace = TRUE,prob=pviajeT)}

  tintervalM[c]<-if(c <300){sample(t_intervalo,size=1, replace=TRUE, prob=pinterM)#VAL 2
  }                     else{
sample(t_intervalo,size=1, replace=T, prob= pinterT)
  }}
```

I previously asgined the number aleat. to the variable tintervalM, and in the second loop I suposed to I only pick the number from the variables aleats. an just sum. I hope to be well explained and be helped.

```
#Loop for times 
for (c in 3:600){

  min.llegada[c]<-min.llegada[c-1]+tllegadasM[c] #VAL 1 
  tinterval[c]<-if(min.llegada[c-1]>tinterval[c-1]){
tinterval[c-1]+ tintervalM[c]+tintervalM[c+1]} #VAL 2 HERE IS THE PROBLEM

  min.salida[c]<-tinterval[c]+tviajeM[c] #VAL 4

  nuevo <- data.frame (caso = c,
                   minuto_llegada = min.llegada[c],#1
                   minuto_inicio_del_viaje = tinterval[c],#2
                   Tiempo_viaje = tviajeM [c],#3
                   minuto_salida_del_cliente = min.salida[c])#4
  sim <- rbind(sim, nuevo)
}
```

I want to asigne the sum of the previos number of tinterval[c-1] plus the number generated by tintervalM[c] and plus next number generated by tintervalM[c] to the variable tinterval[c] if min.salida[c] is greater than tinverval[c],but i recive the error has length zero,

Comment: Your code is very difficult to read as it's long and poorly formatted. I suggest you to trim it down as much as possible. Work on the format as well e.g. put spaces where needed. After that you'll probably receive more responses

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Despite not understanding what your code does, I think I can point to the error. This part will fail if the condition within `if` in not `TRUE`.

```
tinterval[c] <- if(min.llegada[c-1]>tinterval[c-1]){
    tinterval[c-1] + tintervalM[c] + tintervalM[c+1]
} #VAL 2 HERE IS THE PROBLEM
```

If the condition is FALSE, the `if` clause returns NULL and it cannot be assigned to `tinterval[c]`.

How I guess it should be written is as follow

```
if( min.llegada[c-1] > tinterval[c-1] ){
    tinterval[c] <- tinterval[c-1] + tintervalM[c] + tintervalM[c+1]
}
```

Now if the condition is FALSE, nothing happens.

Comment: It suposed to make two counts,  one of them  don´t have to be greater than the other for each [c], if it's TRUE have to keep the previous .
Thank you for you answer, I  have to  add ELSE to the new sentence IF, because the loop can keep going. I finally I get the result that I wanted

Comment: Glad I could help. Adding an `else` clause is clearly a solution too.